# different page template in Yii

Tags: templates, yii

I am implementing a template for a Yii project. The website has different frontpage and inner page template.

I know I have to change layout files, But how can I have those different templates for pages ?

Comment: Are you only changing the main template (the layout of the content on every page) or are you also changing any of the individual controller action views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in the controller. For example my website looks the same except for a few pages. One of them is the login page. In the SiteController I have declared the actionLogin like this:

```
/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $this->layout = '//layouts/simple';
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
        //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        $this->redirect(array('/'));
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

The line $this->layout = '//layouts/simple'; overwrites the default layout (main) with the simple layout. If different controllers use different layouts you can also make this a controller wide change by declaring the variable in the controller

```
public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

Comment: Mihai is right. Alternatively, you can do *<?php $this->layout = '//layouts/simple'; ?>* **in the view** if that makes more sense.